# On Activity Result android Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I've got a problem using camera Intent in my Xamarin application.

```
public class MainFragment : Android.App.Fragment
{
    //some code here

 public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {


            case Resource.Id.action_share:
                try
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);

                    var file = new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory, string.Format("android_camera_{0}.jpg", time));
                    var url = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
                    intent = intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, url);
                    StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Error " + e.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
                break;

        }
        return true;
    }
  public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (resultCode==Result.Ok)
        {
            //progress = new ProgressDialog(ListsActivity.thisActivity);
            //progress.SetMessage(ListsActivity.localizer.Loading());
            //progress.SetCancelable(false);
            //progress.Show();
            //new Thread(ListsFragment.UploadImageAndDeleteIt).Start();
        }
    }
}
```

I created camera intent and tried to work with created image but faced with such problem. Sometimes it runs correctly but mostly my activity recreates after doing photo or app just crashes even without going into OnActivityResult function. I've tested it on 6.0.0 emulator and it works fine but in my real phone on 4.4 it's like 30/70.

Comment: Is there any exception message ? Troubleshooting this issue will be much easier if you include information from the crash.

Comment: It's just exiting application with message "App stoped working" and I don't know how to handle which type of exception is it throwing.

Comment: You could add a try/catch to catch exception.

Comment: Yes, but I have try/catch in creating intent, as you can see and this exception is throwing not in this method or onactivityresult, but somewhere between.

Comment: You could see more information by [diagnostic build output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output)